# How to get all open strings from .h and .m files Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, cocoa, genstrings

I want to create excel of all open strings @"..." in .h and .m files throughout my project.
To standardise strings across platform.
Is there any tool to get strings ?
I used genstrings but it only finds localized strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install BREW first and then GNU grep. -p no longer works with current grep in osx.
    http://www.heystephenwood.com/2013/09/install-gnu-grep-on-mac-osx.html

I used following command after installing GNU grep

```
 grep -rPo --no-filename --include='*.m' '(?<=@")(.*)(?=")'  *  >> outfile.txt
```

regex is not proper but still manageable.

Answer (score 2):

One option can be using 'grep' command recursively on all files in ur project folder ending with .h and .m

Something like:

grep -Po '@" \K.*(?= ")'  inputfilename.h > outfile.txt

The result will be saved in the file outfile.txt.
I have not tested it personally but you can give it a try...

Comment: What is command to apply above command recursively to all files in folder and sub folders ? *.h *.m ??